# jquery check if 3 checboxes are checked not working on iphone

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

so im currently busy working on website where people can vote on 3 ideas.
I made a function that the vote submit button is disabled when someone hasnt selected 3 ideas to vote on, and when he/she does select 3 the submit becomes available. 
the problem is its working perfectly fine on android phones but on iphones it stays disabled when i select 3  but becomes available when i switch from 3 to 2 or 4.
 But that isnt whats supposed to happen anyone got a clue of what could be the problem.

down here is my function in JQuery

```
$('body').on('change','#nieuwetrofeestemmen_table',function () {
   var checked = getCheckedRows('nieuwetrofeestemmen_table');
   if(checked.length < 3 || checked.length >3){
       $('.btnStemmen').prop('disabled', true);
   }
   else {
       $('.btnStemmen').prop('disabled', false);
   }
});
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This should work regardless of the device. But check it with your Iphone. Make sure you have javascript enabled in your settings.

```js
$('#checkboxes').on('change',function () {
   var checked = $('#checkboxes').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
   if(checked.length !== 3){
       $('.btnStemmen').prop('disabled', true);
   }
   else {
       $('.btnStemmen').prop('disabled', false);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox">A</input>
<input type="checkbox">A</input>
<input type="checkbox">A</input>
<input type="checkbox">A</input>
<input type="checkbox">A</input>
<input type="checkbox">A</input>
<input type="checkbox">A</input>
<input type="checkbox">A</input>
<input type="checkbox">A</input>
</div>
<button class="btnStemmen" disabled>Stemmen</button>
```

BTW: `if(checked.length !== 3)` works like your `if(checked.length < 3 || checked.length > 3)` but looks cleaner.

Comment: lil problem on that when i go to the settings in the iphone there ain't an option for javascript in the settings

Comment: Settings > Safari > More/Advanced (or something like that, the last point) > Javascript. I think this option came with IOS 12, but i'm not sure.

Comment: oh lol new problem on ipad and different iphone the whole site freezes when i open up the voting modal